# ¿Cómo iniciar un repositorio descargado de Github en la consola?

Tags: reactjs, github

Quizás esta pregunta es super básica pero no encuentro los comandos en línea para correr un Proyecto de React el cual descargue de un repositorio de Github y al correrlo en la consola con `npm start` me marco error. Ya trate con `npm run dev` e instalar los componentes que se supone no tiene instalados con `npm install`de los que voy leyendo que faltan en la consola, pero tengo entendido que hay una línea de comandos con los que se instalan todos los componentes que son necesarios para que el archivo pueda correr en el localhost, solo que no encontre en Google cuales son y tampoco los conozco.

Este es el link del repositorio que intento correr:

> https://github.com/AntonioErdeljac/Blog-Tutorial

Recien voy aprendiendo tanto acerca de React como de programación, agradezco de antemano cualquier apoyo y comentario!

Comment: Debería funcionar con solo npm install y npm start, puedes editar tu pregunta con el link al repo?

Comment: Claro, en un momento la edito. Intente eso, de hecho vienen algunas instrucciones en el repo pero no me corrio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mira ya probé el repo y me funciona bien

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo unico que hice fue:

```
git clone https://github.com/AntonioErdeljac/Blog-Tutorial.git
cd Blog-Tutorial
cd client
npm install
npm start
```

Mira que si estes en la carpeta que es, prueba borrando los node_modules y reinstalandolos, o vuelve a clonar el repo, tambien puedes complementar tu post con el output que te da la consola y en ese caso modifico mi respuesta.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alejov! Volvere a descargar el repositorio e intentar estos pasos que me indicas, cualquier cosa que obtenga en la consola lo edito en el post. Nuevamente muchas gracias!